# Append agility.js object to custom element?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have found [Agility.js](http://agilityjs.com/) library and I like the way it creates and manipulates objects. However, in all examples, objects are appended to the document (expressed as `$$.document`).

Is it possible to append the object to custom element (i.e tell the view to insert the HTML tag in the custom element).

Comment: Have you tried using syntax like: `$$.(document.getElementById('element_id')).append('stuff');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marc's approach may work, but what I've always done is:

```
$$.document.append(cities, '#cities-container');
```

Basically the second argument to append gives you the ability to pick a selector to shove the new DOM elements in to. Not very intuitive but seems to work OK in my experience.